# PDI pentaho reporting output not working with parameters

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I m using pentaho Data integrator 8.1 and pentaho reporting output component inside a transformation. The report contains a simple integer parameter ${batchno} which is working fine with report designer. But while running the PDI transformation it is unable to substitute the parameter value in the report. Here is the detailed error message i am getting. My data source is Mysql - JDBC connection.

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : Unexpected error

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - ERROR (version 8.1.0.0-365, build 8.1.0.0-365 from 2018-04-30 09.42.24 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - There was an unexpected error processing report 'D:.....\testreport.prpt' to produce file 'D:...\testreport.pdf' with processor: PDF.

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - Failed at query: select id_batch,object_name from pdi_channel_log

**where id_batch =  ${batchno}**

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 -

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.pentahoreporting.PentahoReportingOutput.processReport(PentahoReportingOutput.java:418)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.pentahoreporting.PentahoReportingOutput.processRow(PentahoReportingOutput.java:143)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - Caused by: org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ReportDataFactoryException: Failed at query: select id_batch,object_name from pdi_channel_log

**where id_batch =  ${batchno}**

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.queryData(SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.java:184)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SQLReportDataFactory.queryData(SQLReportDataFactory.java:142)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.CompoundDataFactory.queryStaticInternal(CompoundDataFactory.java:172)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.CompoundDataFactory.queryStatic(CompoundDataFactory.java:154)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.cache.CachingDataFactory.queryInternal(CachingDataFactory.java:408)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.cache.CachingDataFactory.queryStatic(CachingDataFactory.java:151)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.CompoundDataFactory.queryStaticInternal(CompoundDataFactory.java:168)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.CompoundDataFactory.queryStatic(CompoundDataFactory.java:154)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.CompoundDataFactory.queryData(CompoundDataFactory.java:67)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.datarow.DefaultFlowController.performQueryData(DefaultFlowController.java:256)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.datarow.DefaultFlowController.performQuery(DefaultFlowController.java:192)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.states.process.ProcessState.initializeForMasterReport(ProcessState.java:318)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.output.AbstractReportProcessor.prepareReportProcessing(AbstractReportProcessor.java:442)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.layout.output.AbstractReportProcessor.processReport(AbstractReportProcessor.java:1433)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.pentahoreporting.ReportExportTask.execute(ReportExportTask.java:89)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.pentahoreporting.ReportExportTask.run(ReportExportTask.java:76)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.pentahoreporting.PentahoReportingOutput.processReport(PentahoReportingOutput.java:399)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - ... 3 more

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter metadata not available for the given statement

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlParameterMetadata.checkAvailable(MysqlParameterMetadata.java:70)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlParameterMetadata.getParameterClassName(MysqlParameterMetadata.java:143)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.parametrize(SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.java:356)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.parametrizeAndQuery(SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.java:277)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.queryData(SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.java:179)

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - ... 19 more

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - child index = 1, logging object : org.pentaho.di.core.logging.LoggingObject@b66df16 parent=1cfddaa4-866d-4b08-9efb-c2a8842102e1

2018/09/18 17:49:21 - Generate Reports.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=0, U=0, E=1)

Comment: Can you show your transformation and the settings you've put in the pentaho reporting step?  PDI8.1 does have woes with parameters, but not sure if that's this. You could also try building 8.2 to see if it's fixed.

Comment: Make sure you have substitutes variable name correctly. If it is correct then i would suggest to try lower version 8.0

Comment: Cannot substitute parameter. Only variable might be substituted and parameter is passed to transformation step.